# Adding more comboboxItems in combobox with value and Text

Tags: c#, combobox

I have made a own class called ComboBoxitem which have two props: Value and text.

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Value;

    public string Text;

    public ComboBoxItem(string val, string text)
    {

        Value = val;

        Text = text;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }

}
```

Now I want to like to add each time a value and a text to a comboboxitem

Something like this:

```
public ComboBoxItem busstops;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblText.Text = "Timetable Bushours for " + "New Bridge Street-St Dominics";

            busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015503", "New Bridge Street-St Dominics");
            busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015552", "Bothal Street (N-Bound), Byker ");

        /*    comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem ("410000015503", "New Bridge Street-St Dominics"));
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("410000015552", "Bothal Street (N-Bound), Byker "));*/


            comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops);
        }
```

But the problem is only the last item is added (Normal because I always say new ComboboxItem) but How can change the code that he always can add new comboboxitems ?

Thanks!

Comment: mostly because im curious...why doesn't the code you have commented out work?  It looks exactly like its supposed to, and should work just fine.  Do you need the busstops variable somewhere else?  In which case you should make it a collection or list of some sort, rather than a single variable...and which encompasses a different question as well...

Answer (score 1):

Both ComboBox items are different object so you need two ComboBox variables to store them.

```
 busstops1 = new ComboBoxItem("410000015503", "New Bridge Street-St Dominics");
 busstops2 = new ComboBoxItem("410000015552", "Bothal Street (N-Bound), Byker ");


 comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops1);
 comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the `comboBox1.Items` each time you update the `busstops` instance.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblText.Text = "Timetable Bushours for " + "New Bridge Street-St Dominics";

            busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015503", "New Bridge Street-St Dominics");
            comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops);

            busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015552", "Bothal Street (N-Bound), Byker ");
            comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to add after each assignment.

```
        busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015503", "New Bridge Street-St Dominics");

        comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops); // Add this line

        busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015552", "Bothal Street (N-Bound), Byker ");
        comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of ComboBoxItems, add items to the list, and set DataSource of comboBox1 to the list:

```
    List<ComboBoxItem> Items = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
    comboBox1.DataSource = Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblText.Text = "Timetable Bushours for " + "New Bridge Street-St Dominics";

        busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015503", "New Bridge Street-St Dominics");
        comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops);//add this line here

        busstops = new ComboBoxItem("410000015552", "Bothal Street (N-Bound), Byker ");
        comboBox1.Items.Add(busstops);//and again here
    }
```

since you are adding the same value, you have to add that value each time it changes.  By declaring `new`, you are in fact replacing and overwriting the old value.